# Shiny app working within R studio and Chrome locally, but not through the deployed link

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R shiny app which runs fine locally within RStudio, and also in Chrome when I click on "Open with browser" in RStudio. The deployment is also successful without any error. However, when I open it using the link of the web app, the app loads, but crashes as soon as I upload a file in the fileinput (The first action for the user on opening the app is to upload one or more excel files).

Can someone please help in finding out the cause of this error?

Thank you.

Here are the contents of the log file for a single instance of the app:

```
2024-01-03T14:35:22.436279+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Container event from container-9031092: start
2024-01-03T14:35:25.436612+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Running on host: 48934218d462
2024-01-03T14:35:25.443031+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Running as user: uid=10001(shiny) gid=10001(shiny) groups=10001(shiny)
2024-01-03T14:35:25.447334+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Connect version: 2023.09.0
2024-01-03T14:35:25.451874+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: LANG: C.UTF-8
2024-01-03T14:35:25.456499+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Working directory: /srv/connect/apps/App-4
2024-01-03T14:35:25.461457+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Using R 4.1.3
2024-01-03T14:35:25.465829+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: R.home(): /opt/R/4.1.3/lib/R
2024-01-03T14:35:25.470395+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Content will use current R environment
2024-01-03T14:35:25.475007+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: R_LIBS: (unset)
2024-01-03T14:35:25.479082+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: .libPaths(): /opt/R/4.1.3/lib/R/library
2024-01-03T14:35:25.483328+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: shiny version: 1.7.4.1
2024-01-03T14:35:25.487845+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: httpuv version: 1.6.9
2024-01-03T14:35:25.492465+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: rmarkdown version: 2.23
2024-01-03T14:35:25.496905+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: knitr version: 1.43
2024-01-03T14:35:25.501268+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: jsonlite version: 1.8.4
2024-01-03T14:35:25.505656+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2024-01-03T14:35:25.510008+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: htmltools version: 0.5.5
2024-01-03T14:35:25.514236+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: reticulate version: (none)
2024-01-03T14:35:25.518728+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.16
2024-01-03T14:35:25.523084+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.527455+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Starting R with process ID: '37'
2024-01-03T14:35:25.531664+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Shiny application starting ...
2024-01-03T14:35:25.535766+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: ── Attaching core tidyverse packages ──────────────────────── tidyverse 2.0.0 ──
2024-01-03T14:35:25.539940+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: ✔ dplyr     1.1.2     ✔ readr     2.1.4
2024-01-03T14:35:25.544418+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: ✔ forcats   1.0.0     ✔ stringr   1.5.0
2024-01-03T14:35:25.548723+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: ✔ ggplot2   3.4.2     ✔ tibble    3.2.1
2024-01-03T14:35:25.553377+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: ✔ lubridate 1.9.2     ✔ tidyr     1.3.0
2024-01-03T14:35:25.557784+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: ✔ purrr     1.0.1     
2024-01-03T14:35:25.562010+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
2024-01-03T14:35:25.566286+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
2024-01-03T14:35:25.570467+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
2024-01-03T14:35:25.574704+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: ℹ Use the conflicted package (<http://conflicted.r-lib.org/>) to force all conflicts to become errors
2024-01-03T14:35:25.578823+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: here() starts at /srv/connect/apps/App-4
2024-01-03T14:35:25.583068+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.587398+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Attaching package: ‘plotly’
2024-01-03T14:35:25.592053+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.597310+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:
2024-01-03T14:35:25.601673+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.606094+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     last_plot
2024-01-03T14:35:25.610941+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.615070+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:
2024-01-03T14:35:25.619678+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.624099+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     filter
2024-01-03T14:35:25.628222+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.632641+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:
2024-01-03T14:35:25.637594+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.642012+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     layout
2024-01-03T14:35:25.646241+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.650840+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.655112+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Attaching package: ‘reshape2’
2024-01-03T14:35:25.659372+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.663539+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: The following object is masked from ‘package:tidyr’:
2024-01-03T14:35:25.667797+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.672217+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     smiths
2024-01-03T14:35:25.676718+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.681512+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.685718+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Attaching package: ‘data.table’
2024-01-03T14:35:25.690077+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.694332+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:reshape2’:
2024-01-03T14:35:25.698651+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.703150+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     dcast, melt
2024-01-03T14:35:25.707308+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.712354+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:lubridate’:
2024-01-03T14:35:25.718187+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.722668+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     hour, isoweek, mday, minute, month, quarter, second, wday, week,
2024-01-03T14:35:25.727718+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     yday, year
2024-01-03T14:35:25.731871+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.735870+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:
2024-01-03T14:35:25.740027+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.744391+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     between, first, last
2024-01-03T14:35:25.748595+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.753018+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: The following object is masked from ‘package:purrr’:
2024-01-03T14:35:25.760094+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.764315+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     transpose
2024-01-03T14:35:25.768915+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.773369+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.778262+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Attaching package: ‘shinyjs’
2024-01-03T14:35:25.782790+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.786890+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: The following object is masked from ‘package:lubridate’:
2024-01-03T14:35:25.791158+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.795473+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     show
2024-01-03T14:35:25.799826+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.804175+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:
2024-01-03T14:35:25.809106+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.813931+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     runExample
2024-01-03T14:35:25.818308+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.822867+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:methods’:
2024-01-03T14:35:25.827926+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.832401+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     removeClass, show
2024-01-03T14:35:25.836969+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.841266+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: 
2024-01-03T14:35:25.845733+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:36197
2024-01-03T14:35:35.699948+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning: Error in checkName: Must use single string to index into reactivevalues.
2024-01-03T14:35:35.704309+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   189: <Anonymous>
2024-01-03T14:35:35.709124+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   188: signalCondition
2024-01-03T14:35:35.713931+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   187: signal_abort
2024-01-03T14:35:35.718160+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   186: rlang::abort
2024-01-03T14:35:35.723228+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   185: checkName
2024-01-03T14:35:35.727453+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   184: [[.reactivevalues
2024-01-03T14:35:35.731842+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   182: renderPlot [/srv/connect/apps/App-4/app.R#343]
2024-01-03T14:35:35.736320+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   180: func
2024-01-03T14:35:35.740656+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   140: drawPlot
2024-01-03T14:35:35.745027+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   126: <reactive:plotObj>
2024-01-03T14:35:35.749653+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   110: drawReactive
2024-01-03T14:35:35.754181+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    97: renderFunc
2024-01-03T14:35:35.758351+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    96: output$live_plot_1
2024-01-03T14:35:35.762775+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    15: <Anonymous>
2024-01-03T14:35:35.766954+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    13: fn
2024-01-03T14:35:35.771624+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     8: retry
2024-01-03T14:35:35.775642+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     7: connect$retryingStartServer
2024-01-03T14:35:35.779719+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     6: eval
2024-01-03T14:35:35.784013+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     5: eval
2024-01-03T14:35:35.788768+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     4: eval
2024-01-03T14:35:35.793150+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     3: eval
2024-01-03T14:35:35.797542+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     2: eval.parent
2024-01-03T14:35:35.801912+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     1: local
2024-01-03T14:35:37.436584+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in renderPlot() : NAs introduced by coercion
2024-01-03T14:37:19.439627+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: New names:
2024-01-03T14:37:19.444255+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: • `Product (result)` -> `Product (result)...8`
2024-01-03T14:37:19.453509+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: • `Product (result)` -> `Product (result)...9`
2024-01-03T14:37:19.458020+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in lapply(file_to_add, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
2024-01-03T14:37:19.462603+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in lapply(file_to_add, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
2024-01-03T14:37:19.467085+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in lapply(file_to_add, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
2024-01-03T14:37:19.471434+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in lapply(file_to_add, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
2024-01-03T14:37:19.475856+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in lapply(file_to_add, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
2024-01-03T14:37:19.480280+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in lapply(file_to_add, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
2024-01-03T14:37:19.484677+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in lapply(file_to_add, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
2024-01-03T14:37:19.489634+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: New names:
2024-01-03T14:37:19.493982+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: • `Product (result)` -> `Product (result)...8`
2024-01-03T14:37:19.498317+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: • `Product (result)` -> `Product (result)...9`
2024-01-03T14:37:19.503181+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: [1] "null result"
2024-01-03T14:37:19.507552+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: [1] TRUE
2024-01-03T14:37:19.512268+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: [1] "i"
2024-01-03T14:37:19.516607+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning: Error in print: object 'i' not found
2024-01-03T14:37:19.521041+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   15: <Anonymous>
2024-01-03T14:37:19.525661+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   13: fn
2024-01-03T14:37:19.530333+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    8: retry
2024-01-03T14:37:19.535078+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    7: connect$retryingStartServer
2024-01-03T14:37:19.539802+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    6: eval
2024-01-03T14:37:19.544201+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    5: eval
2024-01-03T14:37:19.548736+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    4: eval
2024-01-03T14:37:19.554963+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    3: eval
2024-01-03T14:37:19.559702+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    2: eval.parent
2024-01-03T14:37:19.564200+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    1: local
2024-01-03T14:37:19.568670+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in renderPrint() : NAs introduced by coercion
2024-01-03T14:37:19.573156+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in paste0(as.integer(input$file_num)) :
2024-01-03T14:37:19.577611+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   NAs introduced by coercion
2024-01-03T14:37:19.582066+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning: Error in [: incorrect number of dimensions
2024-01-03T14:37:19.586688+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   116: nearPoints
2024-01-03T14:37:19.591138+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   114: renderPrint [/srv/connect/apps/App-4/app.R#368]
2024-01-03T14:37:19.595366+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   113: func
2024-01-03T14:37:19.599926+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    97: renderFunc
2024-01-03T14:37:19.604391+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    96: output$click_info
2024-01-03T14:37:19.608782+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    15: <Anonymous>
2024-01-03T14:37:19.613868+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    13: fn
2024-01-03T14:37:19.618320+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     8: retry
2024-01-03T14:37:19.622621+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     7: connect$retryingStartServer
2024-01-03T14:37:19.627147+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     6: eval
2024-01-03T14:37:19.631710+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     5: eval
2024-01-03T14:37:19.635877+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     4: eval
2024-01-03T14:37:19.640282+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     3: eval
2024-01-03T14:37:19.644846+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     2: eval.parent
2024-01-03T14:37:19.649922+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     1: local
2024-01-03T14:37:19.654448+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in renderPlot() : NAs introduced by coercion
2024-01-03T14:37:19.658738+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2024-01-03T14:37:19.663374+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2024-01-03T14:37:19.667826+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2024-01-03T14:37:19.672426+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2024-01-03T14:37:19.677098+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]: Warning: Error in plot.window: need finite 'xlim' values
2024-01-03T14:37:19.681746+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   186: plot.window
2024-01-03T14:37:19.686496+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   185: localWindow
2024-01-03T14:37:19.691071+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   184: plot.default
2024-01-03T14:37:19.695844+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   182: renderPlot [/srv/connect/apps/App-4/app.R#568]
2024-01-03T14:37:19.700523+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   180: func
2024-01-03T14:37:19.705546+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   140: drawPlot
2024-01-03T14:37:19.710415+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   126: <reactive:plotObj>
2024-01-03T14:37:19.715251+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:   110: drawReactive
2024-01-03T14:37:19.719862+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    97: renderFunc
2024-01-03T14:37:19.724345+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    96: output$live_plot_2
2024-01-03T14:37:19.728727+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    15: <Anonymous>
2024-01-03T14:37:19.732995+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:    13: fn
2024-01-03T14:37:19.737526+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     8: retry
2024-01-03T14:37:19.741896+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     7: connect$retryingStartServer
2024-01-03T14:37:19.745964+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     6: eval
2024-01-03T14:37:19.750216+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     5: eval
2024-01-03T14:37:19.754397+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     4: eval
2024-01-03T14:37:19.759216+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     3: eval
2024-01-03T14:37:19.763514+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     2: eval.parent
2024-01-03T14:37:19.768114+00:00 shinyapps[10608803]:     1: local
```

Comment: Find the log file(s) on the remote server, there is likely one (or more) error there.

Comment: @r2evans I have edited my post and added the contents of the log file. Can you please have a look at these and suggest which of these could be causing the problem? None of these errors are causing any issue while running the app locally. Thanks

Comment: It's a start, but ... I don't have the code. Heed the warnings and errors, though: `single string to index` suggests that you have a `reactiveValues` object and are trying to `[`-index it with a character vector of length greater than 1, don't do that; `object 'i' not found` is a clear error, this is obviously breaking things. Most warnings and errors after  that can be ignored for now until you fix the first couple of issues. BTW, I suspect that you might  have variables in your local R instance (e.g., `i`) that cause this error to not appear for you. Start in a fresh R instance and try again

Comment: @r2evans The error was due to the variable ```i``` like you suggested. There was a print statement which printed the variable, and removing all the print statements from my code solved the problem. Thank you.